# IPSec tranport - ESP ping packet is sent but no reply is sent

Tags: linux, networking, ipsec

I've tried to establish connection between two hosts but I cannot get it to work. When I send a ping packet I see that ESP packet is received but no reply is sent. What can be wrong?

```
conn core-02
    type=transport
    leftid=@core-01
    left=172.17.8.101
    leftrsasigkey=<...>
    rightid=@core-02
    right=172.17.8.102
    rightrsasigkey=<...>
    authby=rsasig
    auto=start
```

And logs:

```
pluto[7261]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
pluto[7261]: loaded private key for keyid: PPK_RSA:AQPY0vkGg
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: initiating Main Mode
pluto[7261]: reapchild failed with errno=10 No child processes
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: Main mode peer ID is ID_FQDN: '@core-02'
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I3 to state STATE_MAIN_I4
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=RSA_SIG cipher=aes_256 integ=sha group=MODP2048}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #2: initiating Quick Mode RSASIG+ENCRYPT+PFS+UP+IKEV1_ALLOW+IKEV2_ALLOW+SAREF_TRACK+IKE_FRAG_ALLOW+ESN_NO {using isakmp#1 msgid:b77212e6 proposal=defaults pfsgroup=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #2: transition from state STATE_QUICK_I1 to state STATE_QUICK_I2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP=>0xa23882f0 <0x5748fb27 xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=passive}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: responding to Main Mode
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R0 to state STATE_MAIN_R1
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: STATE_MAIN_R1: sent MR1, expecting MI2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R1 to state STATE_MAIN_R2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: STATE_MAIN_R2: sent MR2, expecting MI3
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: Main mode peer ID is ID_FQDN: '@core-02'
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R2 to state STATE_MAIN_R3
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: STATE_MAIN_R3: sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established {auth=RSA_SIG cipher=aes_256 integ=sha group=MODP2048}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #3: the peer proposed: 172.17.8.101/32:0/0 -> 172.17.8.102/32:0/0
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: responding to Quick Mode proposal {msgid:c65e8e64}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4:     us: 172.17.8.101<172.17.8.101>[@core-01]
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4:   them: 172.17.8.102<172.17.8.102>[@core-02]
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: keeping refhim=0 during rekey
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: transition from state STATE_QUICK_R0 to state STATE_QUICK_R1
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: STATE_QUICK_R1: sent QR1, inbound IPsec SA installed, expecting QI2 transport mode {ESP=>0x6dc4662c <0x2babef51 xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=passive}
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: transition from state STATE_QUICK_R1 to state STATE_QUICK_R2
pluto[7261]: "core-02" #4: STATE_QUICK_R2: IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP=>0x6dc4662c <0x2babef51 xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=passive}
```

Possibly relevant:

```
# cat /proc/net/xfrm_stat
XfrmInError                 0
XfrmInBufferError           0
XfrmInHdrError              0
XfrmInNoStates              120
XfrmInStateProtoError       0
XfrmInStateModeError        12
XfrmInStateSeqError         0
XfrmInStateExpired          0
XfrmInStateMismatch         0
XfrmInStateInvalid          0
XfrmInTmplMismatch          17677
XfrmInNoPols                10
XfrmInPolBlock              0
XfrmInPolError              0
XfrmOutError                0
XfrmOutBundleGenError       0
XfrmOutBundleCheckError     0
XfrmOutNoStates             55358
XfrmOutStateProtoError      0
XfrmOutStateModeError       0
XfrmOutStateSeqError        0
XfrmOutStateExpired         0
XfrmOutPolBlock             0
XfrmOutPolDead              0
XfrmOutPolError             0
XfrmFwdHdrError             0
XfrmOutStateInvalid         9
XfrmAcquireError            0
# ipsec verify --nocolour 2>&1 | sed 's:^:    :g;'
Verifying installed system and configuration files

Version check and ipsec on-path                     [OK]
Libreswan 3.18 (netkey) on 4.7.0-coreos
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                [OK]
 NETKEY: Testing XFRM related proc values
         ICMP default/send_redirects                [OK]
         ICMP default/accept_redirects              [OK]
         XFRM larval drop                           [OK]
Pluto ipsec.conf syntax                             [OK]
Hardware random device                              [N/A]
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding    [OK]
Checking rp_filter                                  [OK]
Checking that pluto is running                      [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                 [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on udp 4500          [OK]
 Pluto ipsec.secret syntax                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/libexec/ipsec/verify", line 477, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/libexec/ipsec/verify", line 466, in main
    plutocheck()
  File "/usr/libexec/ipsec/verify", line 121, in plutocheck
    ipsecsecretcheck()
  File "/usr/libexec/ipsec/verify", line 375, in ipsecsecretcheck
    output = output.decode(prefencoding)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**EDIT** Example of receiving ping packets from core-02 (tcpdump executed on core-01) - note lack of decrypted packages:

```
19:16:41.387778 IP 172.17.8.102 > core-01: ESP(spi=0xd6c60341,seq=0x1), length 100
19:16:42.387542 IP 172.17.8.102 > core-01: ESP(spi=0xd6c60341,seq=0x2), length 100
19:16:43.388239 IP 172.17.8.102 > core-01: ESP(spi=0xd6c60341,seq=0x3), length 100
19:16:44.388052 IP 172.17.8.102 > core-01: ESP(spi=0xd6c60341,seq=0x4), length 100
```

And policy corresponding to it (note that algorithm does not match config above but this doesn't matter):

```
# sudo ip xfrm policy
src 172.17.8.101/32 dst 172.17.8.102/32 
    dir out priority 2080 ptype main 
    tmpl src 0.0.0.0 dst 0.0.0.0
        proto esp reqid 16389 mode transport
src 172.17.8.102/32 dst 172.17.8.101/32 
    dir in priority 2080 ptype main 
    tmpl src 0.0.0.0 dst 0.0.0.0
        proto esp reqid 16389 mode transport
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135 
    dir fwd priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135 
    dir in priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136 
    dir out priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136 
    dir fwd priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136 
    dir in priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135 
    dir out priority 1 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 ptype main 
# ip xfrm state
src 172.17.8.102 dst 172.17.8.101
    proto esp spi 0xd6c60341 reqid 16389 mode transport
    replay-window 32 
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0x22f23f67917af5384d4ce84ec77b2c0ad7ab8ead3f2c704263c54953273613becf08b744 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
    sel src 172.17.8.102/32 dst 172.17.8.101/32 
src 172.17.8.101 dst 172.17.8.102
    proto esp spi 0x0e6d238f reqid 16389 mode transport
    replay-window 32 
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0x380b1914db9a87df053f239d219becef070b45149f1902a05798e7c6dae286161314905d 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
    sel src 172.17.8.101/32 dst 172.17.8.102/32 
src 172.17.8.102 dst 172.17.8.101
    proto esp spi 0xafe1a0e7 reqid 16389 mode transport
    replay-window 32 
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0x81502cdd71de6ad1ca8fee932fc988ebdad935ef5e00afff85ca72b908f33675b2d9c849 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
    sel src 172.17.8.102/32 dst 172.17.8.101/32 
src 172.17.8.101 dst 172.17.8.102
    proto esp spi 0x17074ed6 reqid 16389 mode transport
    replay-window 32 
    aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0xbf29e49cb147c9887f8d9321cb08db6aa01248a06cb0444ca70cb71e9df2d1d60a9d25f2 128
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
    sel src 172.17.8.101/32 dst 172.17.8.102/32
```

**EDIT**: Requested `ipsec auto --status`

```
# ipsec auto --status
000 using kernel interface: netkey
000 interface lo/lo ::1@500
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1@4500
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1@500
000 interface eth0/eth0 10.0.2.15@4500
000 interface eth0/eth0 10.0.2.15@500
000 interface eth1/eth1 172.17.8.101@4500
000 interface eth1/eth1 172.17.8.101@500
000 interface flannel0/flannel0 10.1.73.0@4500
000 interface flannel0/flannel0 10.1.73.0@500
000  
000  
000 fips mode=disabled;
000 SElinux=disabled
000  
000 config setup options:
000  
000 configdir=/etc, configfile=/etc/ipsec.conf, secrets=/etc/ipsec.secrets, ipsecdir=/etc/ipsec.d, dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/, statsbin=unset
000 sbindir=/usr/sbin, libexecdir=/usr/libexec/ipsec
000 pluto_version=3.15, pluto_vendorid=OE-Libreswan-3.15
000 nhelpers=-1, uniqueids=yes, perpeerlog=no, shuntlifetime=900s, xfrmlifetime=300s
000 ddos-cookies-treshold=50000, ddos-max-halfopen=25000, ddos-mode=auto
000 ikeport=500, strictcrlpolicy=no, crlcheckinterval=0, listen=<any>, nflog-all=0
000 secctx-attr-type=32001
000 myid = (none)
000 debug none
000  
000 nat-traversal=yes, keep-alive=20, nat-ikeport=4500
000 virtual-private (%priv):
000 - allowed subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 25.0.0.0/8, 100.64.0.0/10, fd00::/8, fe80::/10
000  
000 ESP algorithms supported:
000  
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=3, name=ESP_3DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=192, keysizemax=192
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=11, name=ESP_NULL, ivlen=0, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=12, name=ESP_AES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=13, name=ESP_AES_CTR, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=14, name=ESP_AES_CCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=15, name=ESP_AES_CCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=16, name=ESP_AES_CCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=18, name=ESP_AES_GCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=19, name=ESP_AES_GCM_B, ivlen=12, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=20, name=ESP_AES_GCM_C, ivlen=16, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm AH/ESP auth: id=1, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_MD5, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm AH/ESP auth: id=2, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA1, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm AH/ESP auth: id=5, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_256, keysizemin=256, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm AH/ESP auth: id=251, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_NULL_KAME, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000  
000 IKE algorithms supported:
000  
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=0, v1name=0??, v2id=16, v2name=AES_CCM_C, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=0, v1name=0??, v2id=15, v2name=AES_CCM_B, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=0, v1name=0??, v2id=14, v2name=AES_CCM_A, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=5, v1name=OAKLEY_3DES_CBC, v2id=3, v2name=3DES, blocksize=8, keydeflen=192
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=24, v1name=OAKLEY_CAMELLIA_CTR, v2id=24, v2name=CAMELLIA_CTR, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=8, v1name=OAKLEY_CAMELLIA_CBC, v2id=23, v2name=CAMELLIA_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=20, v1name=OAKLEY_AES_GCM_C, v2id=20, v2name=AES_GCM_C, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=19, v1name=OAKLEY_AES_GCM_B, v2id=19, v2name=AES_GCM_B, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=18, v1name=OAKLEY_AES_GCM_A, v2id=18, v2name=AES_GCM_A, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=13, v1name=OAKLEY_AES_CTR, v2id=13, v2name=AES_CTR, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=7, v1name=OAKLEY_AES_CBC, v2id=12, v2name=AES_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=65004, v1name=OAKLEY_SERPENT_CBC, v2id=65004, v2name=SERPENT_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=65005, v1name=OAKLEY_TWOFISH_CBC, v2id=65005, v2name=TWOFISH_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: v1id=65289, v1name=OAKLEY_TWOFISH_CBC_SSH, v2id=65289, v2name=TWOFISH_CBC_SSH, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=1, name=OAKLEY_MD5, hashlen=16
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=2, name=OAKLEY_SHA1, hashlen=20
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=4, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_256, hashlen=32
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=5, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_384, hashlen=48
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=6, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_512, hashlen=64
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=9, name=DISABLED-OAKLEY_AES_XCBC, hashlen=16
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=2, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=5, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1536, bits=1536
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=14, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=15, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP3072, bits=3072
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=16, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP4096, bits=4096
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=17, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP6144, bits=6144
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=18, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP8192, bits=8192
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=22, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=23, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH23, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=24, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH24, bits=2048
000  
000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,0,0} trans={0,0,0} attrs={0,0,0} 
000  
000 Connection list:
000  
000 "core-02": 172.17.8.101<172.17.8.101>[@core-01]...172.17.8.102<172.17.8.102>[@core-02]; erouted; eroute owner: #2
000 "core-02":     oriented; my_ip=unset; their_ip=unset
000 "core-02":   xauth info: us:none, them:none,  my_xauthuser=[any]; their_xauthuser=[any]
000 "core-02":   modecfg info: us:none, them:none, modecfg policy:push, dns1:unset, dns2:unset, domain:unset, banner:unset;
000 "core-02":   labeled_ipsec:no;
000 "core-02":   policy_label:unset;
000 "core-02":   ike_life: 3600s; ipsec_life: 28800s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 0;
000 "core-02":   retransmit-interval: 500ms; retransmit-timeout: 60s;
000 "core-02":   sha2_truncbug:no; initial_contact:no; cisco_unity:no; send_vendorid:no;
000 "core-02":   policy: RSASIG+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+PFS+UP+IKEV1_ALLOW+IKEV2_ALLOW+SAREF_TRACK+IKE_FRAG_ALLOW;
000 "core-02":   conn_prio: 32,32; interface: eth1; metric: 0; mtu: unset; sa_prio:auto; nflog-group: unset;
000 "core-02":   newest ISAKMP SA: #1; newest IPsec SA: #2;
000 "core-02":   IKE algorithm newest: AES_CBC_256-SHA1-MODP2048
000 "core-02":   ESP algorithm newest: AES_128-HMAC_SHA1; pfsgroup=<Phase1>
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in": ::/0===::1<::1>:58/34560...%any:58/34816===::/0; prospective erouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":     oriented; my_ip=unset; their_ip=unset
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   xauth info: us:none, them:none,  my_xauthuser=[any]; their_xauthuser=[any]
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   modecfg info: us:none, them:none, modecfg policy:push, dns1:unset, dns2:unset, domain:unset, banner:unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   labeled_ipsec:no;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   policy_label:unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   ike_life: 0s; ipsec_life: 0s; rekey_margin: 0s; rekey_fuzz: 0%; keyingtries: 0;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   retransmit-interval: 0ms; retransmit-timeout: 0s;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   sha2_truncbug:no; initial_contact:no; cisco_unity:no; send_vendorid:no;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   policy: PFS+IKEV1_ALLOW+IKEV2_ALLOW+SAREF_TRACK+IKE_FRAG_ALLOW+PASS+NEVER_NEGOTIATE;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   conn_prio: 0,0; interface: lo; metric: 0; mtu: unset; sa_prio:1; nflog-group: unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-in":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out": ::/0===::1<::1>:58/34816...%any:58/34560===::/0; prospective erouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":     oriented; my_ip=unset; their_ip=unset
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   xauth info: us:none, them:none,  my_xauthuser=[any]; their_xauthuser=[any]
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   modecfg info: us:none, them:none, modecfg policy:push, dns1:unset, dns2:unset, domain:unset, banner:unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   labeled_ipsec:no;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   policy_label:unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   ike_life: 0s; ipsec_life: 0s; rekey_margin: 0s; rekey_fuzz: 0%; keyingtries: 0;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   retransmit-interval: 0ms; retransmit-timeout: 0s;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   sha2_truncbug:no; initial_contact:no; cisco_unity:no; send_vendorid:no;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   policy: PFS+IKEV1_ALLOW+IKEV2_ALLOW+SAREF_TRACK+IKE_FRAG_ALLOW+PASS+NEVER_NEGOTIATE;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   conn_prio: 0,0; interface: lo; metric: 0; mtu: unset; sa_prio:1; nflog-group: unset;
000 "v6neighbor-hole-out":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0;
000  
000 Total IPsec connections: loaded 3, active 1
000  
000 State Information: DDoS cookies not required, Accepting new IKE connections
000 IKE SAs: total(1), half-open(0), open(0), authenticated(1), anonymous(0)
000 IPsec SAs: total(1), authenticated(1), anonymous(0)
000  
000 #2: "core-02":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 25818s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#1; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #2: "core-02" esp.81ccb49e@172.17.8.102 esp.8ff9d69f@172.17.8.101 tun.0@172.17.8.102 tun.0@172.17.8.101 ref=0 refhim=4294901761 Traffic: ESPout=603KB ESPin=579KB! ESPmax=4194303B 
000 #1: "core-02":500 STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 377s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=-1s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:admin initiate
000  
000 Bare Shunt list:
000
```

Comment: These logs don't indicate in any way that the icmp request was received.

Comment: It looks like the tunnel is up, because IPSec SA is established.  Check the routing on the far endpoint: when it gets a PING, will it know to respond to the sender via the far IPSec endpoint?  Also, check firewalls to ensure the PING is getting through them.  This sort of diagnosis is *much* easier if you can ssh into waypoints *en route*.

Comment: @MadHatter - There is no 'in route' - it's one physical network (well - 'physical' inside VM). I see that ESP packets are received by tcpdump. On second endpoint I see that routes are correct and it can also send ESP packets (which are received by second side). The iptables configuration is default (i.e. ACCEPT).

Comment: These two VMs could ping each other before you brought the tunnel up, yes?

Comment: @MadHatter yes, and they can after i get the tunnel down. Reading up it looks like there is 'policy mismatch' - whatever it is caused by.

Comment: You might be right, but I'm sceptical.  In my experience, once IPSec SA is established, everything is completely functional - that's pretty much how IPSec defines a functional tunnel.  On the *destination* system, if you do a `tcpdump -n -n -i eth0` (or interface as appropriate), do you see the ESP traffic coming in, plus the decrypted inbound payload?

Comment: @MadHatter - No, just ESP but no decrypted payload. The SPI matches one from `xfrm policy`. See after edit at attempt of ping from core-02 to core-01.

Comment: I saw the tcpdump output. but you didn't show the *command*, only the output, so it was impossible to know what I *wasn't* seeing, if you see what I mean.  Could we get `ipsec auto --status` on the receiving system?

Comment: @MadHatter: Here you go.

Comment: I am by no means sure about this, but it is possible that I am seeing signs of a mismatch about the connection type (some of what you show suggests transport mode, some suggests tunnel mode).  Could you configure both ends to `type=tunnel`, delete and re-add the tunnel at both ends, bring it up, repeat the ping test and tcpdump, and update the information?

Comment: @MadHatter The same. Ditto for transport (I tried with transport before).

Comment: I note you haven't updated *any* of the information in the question.  I'm fairly out of hypotheses myself, I'm afraid - but if you hope for people to generate ideas, you do need to give them current, and self-consistent, data to work on.